# How do I center the post title?

Tags: html, css, genesis

How do I center the title "BOASISH IS UNDER CONSTRUCTION" but keep By Kyle Boas · Follow: Twitter, Google+
September 4, 2014 as it is. My website is http://boasish.com, if you get a error page then use http://orangina.asmallorange.com/~boasishc/ as the url instead of http://boasish.com

```
<h2 class="entry-title" itemprop="headline"><a href="http://orangina.asmallorange.com/~boasishc/site-under-construction/" rel="bookmark">Boasish is Under Construction</a></h2>
    <a href="http://orangina.asmallorange.com/~boasishc/site-under-construction/" rel="bookmark">Boasish is Under Construction</a>
</h2>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add this code to you css

```
.entry-header h2{
   text-align: center;
   width: 100%;
}
```

or just add this code

```
.entry-header{
   text-align: center;
}

header .entry-meta{
   text-align: left;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Ok that worked, how do I shrink the grey line underneath the title so it hugs the B and N of BOASISH IS UNDER CONSTRUCTION?

Answer (score 1):

Change

`<h2 class="entry-title" itemprop="headline">`

To

`<h2 class="entry-title" itemprop="headline" style="text-align: center;">`

Answer (score 1):

You could add `text-align: center` and `width: 100%` in your `style` attribute.

```
<h2 class="entry-title" style="text-align: center; width: 100%;" itemprop="headline"><a href="http://orangina.asmallorange.com/~boasishc/site-under-construction/" rel="bookmark">Boasish is Under Construction</a></h2>
    <a href="http://orangina.asmallorange.com/~boasishc/site-under-construction/" rel="bookmark">Boasish is Under Construction</a>
</h2>
```